# first_or_initialize calling block even though row is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In one of my models, I'm calling

```
puts where(field: value).first
where(field: value).first_or_initialize.tap do |row|
      # . . . Actual creation and saving omitted
end
```

I've run it a few times just to test it, and the block keeps being run even though I can see plainly that it shouldn't be (because `puts` is printing a found row and because there is actually something in the database). I also know that the block is being called because I have some omitted `puts` in there and SQL is calling updates.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: [`first_or_initialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize) does just that. If it finds a record, it will do something with it, else it will create a new record and do something with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into how `tap` works. The crux is that with `tap` you basically, tap into the object and operate the block on it. In this case, you don't need `tap` at all. This is what you need:

```
Model.where(conditions).first_or_initialize do |row|
  # code
end
```

More or less, the same code but without `tap`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't understanding that clearly, as I essentially found that code sample. That makes sense, though, so thank you!